# C++ special characters in a regular expression

Tags: c++, expression

I have to parse a regular expression which can contain special symbols such as \s and *\d*. The problem is, I can't distinguish the *\* when i am parsing the expression, I mean *'\s' == 's'*, therefore I cannot distinguish between special character and basic character. How can I solve this?

Comment: probably https://regex101.com/ can help you?

Comment: No. I have a given expression: `a\sb` which will be different from `asb`, but i cannot catch the single *\\* to parse it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) since C++11 can help you to improve the readability:

```
"a\\sb" // matches: a[whitespace]b
"a\\\\sb" // matches: a\sb
```

becomes:

```
R"(a\sb)" // matches: a[whitespace]b
R"(a\\sb)" // matches: a\sb
```

Comment: I think your second examples should read "`matches: a\\sb`" - note the "s" before the "b"

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing user input and character literals. You catch the user input `\` by comparing all input characters with the character literal `'\\'`.